# Realizar for en template literals JS

Tags: javascript, template-strings

Existe alguna manera de realizar un for dentro de un template literal en js?

Recupero de un JSON y accedo a ellos en un primer for y todo va bien pero, después la clave de Permisos tiene un valor del tipo arreglo, por eso quería saber si se puede realizar dígamos algo así:

```
for (let fila of r) {
        tablaNotas.appendChild(stringToRowNode(
            `<div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#${fila["IdUsuario"]}${fila["IdPermiso"]}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="${fila["IdUsuario"]}${fila["IdPermiso"]}">
                        ${ fila["Email"].toString().toUpperCase()}
                        </a>
                      </h4>
                      <button type="button" class="collpase-button collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#${fila["IdUsuario"]}${fila["IdPermiso"]}"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" id="${fila["IdUsuario"]}${fila["IdPermiso"]}">
                      <div class="panel-body">

                            for(let ${p} of ${ fila["Permisos"] }) {
                                <p>${ p["IdPermiso"] }</p>
                                <p>${ p["Nombre"] }</p>
                            }

                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>`
        ));
    }
```

Eso es lo que trato de hacer.

Es esto posible o existe alguna función que me permita realizar algo parecido?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No como quieres, pero en un *string template* puedes poner cualquier código entre `${ }` que devuelva algo. Por tanto podrías crear lo siguiente:

```js
let array = ['A','B','C']

let string = 
`<ul>
  ${array.map(elem => `<li>${elem}</li>`).join('')}
</ul>`;

document.body.innerHTML+=string;
```

Por tanto, tu bucle for

```
for(let ${p} of ${ fila["Permisos"] }) {
  <p>${ p["IdPermiso"] }</p>
  <p>${ p["Nombre"] }</p>
}
```

se podría transformar en:

```
${fila.Permisos.map(p => `<p>${p.IdPermiso}</p> <p>${p.Nombre}</p>`).join('')}
```

Comment: gracias!! me vino de perlas!!

Answer (score 4):

Podrías hacerlo de esta forma.

Donde recorres primeramente el arreglo y sumas las filas correspondientes, después insertas el resultados a tu template.

```js
let arreglo = [{"IdPermiso": 1, "Nombre": "Admin"}, {"IdPermiso": 2, "Nombre": "User"}];
let parrafos = '';
for(let p of arreglo) {
         parrafos += `<p>${ p["IdPermiso"] } / ${ p["Nombre"] }</p>`;
      }
let texto = `<div class="panel-body">${parrafos}</div>`;


document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = texto;
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Lo siento, estuvo demás incluir jQuery. Ya modificado.

Comment: Sí de hecho no lo utilizo, ya edité la pregunta para que quede un poco más claro a que me refiero